# Extracting mutiple values from an XML string stored in a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Trying to extract data from a column whose values are in XML like below which lists when a report runs during the week:

```
WeeklyRecurrence <WeeksInterval>1</WeeksInterval><DaysOfWeek><Sunday>false</Sunday><Monday>true</Monday><Tuesday>false</Tuesday><Wednesday>true</Wednesday><Thursday>false</Thursday><Friday>true</Friday><Saturday>false</Saturday></DaysOfWeek></WeeklyRecurrence>
```

how would I get to a result like:

```
Monday true
Wednesday true
Friday true
```

I have tried using Substring and Charindex  but this am only able to get the 1st row.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you had a look at XQUERY? I ***assume*** your data is valid xml, and is in the `xml` datatype; although currently is isn't valid XML, as it closes with a `WeeklyRecurrence` tag, however, it is not a tag at the start.

Comment: In all fairness, if your data is in a table, Jeroen Mostert answer is the better solution because he using the CROSS APPLY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(schedule XML);
INSERT @t(schedule) VALUES (N'<WeeklyRecurrence><WeeksInterval>1</WeeksInterval><DaysOfWeek><Sunday>false</Sunday><Monday>true</Monday><Tuesday>false</Tuesday><Wednesday>true</Wednesday><Thursday>false</Thursday><Friday>true</Friday><Saturday>false</Saturday></DaysOfWeek></WeeklyRecurrence>');

SELECT 
    [day] = x.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    [present] = x.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
FROM @t 
CROSS APPLY schedule.nodes('/WeeklyRecurrence/DaysOfWeek/*') w(x)
```

```
+-----------+---------+
|    day    | present |
+-----------+---------+
| Sunday    | false   |
| Monday    | true    |
| Tuesday   | false   |
| Wednesday | true    |
| Thursday  | false   |
| Friday    | true    |
| Saturday  | false   |
+-----------+---------+
```

Season to taste if the table has multiple rows -- you'll need to extract another value (`WeeksInterval`? `@t.ID`?) to distinguish the results further in this case.

Comment: Plus 1 for seeing the the "Table" ... I missed that

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example of using `Nodes()`

I'm not sure if you wanted just the TRUE values

```
Declare @XML xml = '<WeeklyRecurrence><WeeksInterval>1</WeeksInterval><DaysOfWeek><Sunday>false</Sunday><Monday>true</Monday><Tuesday>false</Tuesday><Wednesday>true</Wednesday><Thursday>false</Thursday><Friday>true</Friday><Saturday>false</Saturday></DaysOfWeek></WeeklyRecurrence>'

Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)')
      ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(100)')
From  @XML.nodes('//WeeklyRecurrence/DaysOfWeek/*') xNode(xAttr)
```

**Returns**

```
Item        Value
Sunday      false
Monday      true
Tuesday     false
Wednesday   true
Thursday    false
Friday      true
Saturday    false
```

Comment: Thanks John , This work great. I wasn't familiar with Nodes(). I'l do some reading into this.